# ruby on rails, chain commands for filters

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

one minor question, i have a command which displays just the upcoming events, this works fine

```
@events = Event.where("startdate >= ?", Date.today).order("startdate, starttime")
```

now i have a filter which selects just a target group. such as men, women.

```
case params[:filter]
    when "Men" 
        @events = Event.men
    when "Women" 
        @events = Event.women 
    when "Juniors"
        @events = Event.juniors
    else
        @events = Event.all
```

the problem is now i want to combine these two filters, more so in a way that i don't need to repeat the '.where(...)' every line. What would be a good way to solve that. do i need to update my scopes e.g. men, women so that they display just the upcoming events or can i solve that in the controller?

Cheers
Lenny

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you call `Event.men` or other scope, it will not get evaluated right away. So if `params[:filter] = 'Men'`, doing

```
case params[:filter]
    when "Men" 
        @events = Event.men
    when "Women" 
        @events = Event.women 
    when "Juniors"
        @events = Event.juniors
    else
        @events = Event.all
    end
@events = @events.where("startdate >= ?", Date.today).order("startdate, starttime")
```

will build an expression:

```
@events = Event.men.where("startdate >= ?", Date.today).order("startdate, starttime")
```

And only then it will be fetched from DB.

Answer (score 1):

it's hard to figure out what Event.women would be but I'll make an assumption that there's some type column in the events table.

In that case, I'd create a method on Event like this:

```
def self.upcoming type
  Event.where("startdate >= ? and type = ?", Date.today, type).order("startdate, starttime")
end
```

and handle your default case properly. Put your switch in the class method. having that in the controller is a code smell in my opinion.

Comment: i have a column where the corresponding team ist dispalyed and filter accordingly. but so far i am displaying all events for each team. So i just want to display the upcoming events for each team.

Comment: ok, it's a bit of a matter of style but I personally would prefer a class method that was `Event.upcomging_by_team team_type`. It really depends if that is going to be used in other parts of the app. It just looks like too much logic in the controller. This is what models are for.

Answer (score 0):

This is an `ActiveRecord::Relation`:

```
@events = Event.where("startdate >= ?", Date.today)
               .order("startdate, starttime")
```

which remains a *potential* chain of conditions until something forces it to become *concrete*.

This means that you can keep adding conditions to the `@events` relation, like in Felix's answer.

Personally, I like to extract this kind of logic in a private method:

```
class MyController < ApplicationController

  def index
    @events = Event.where("startdate >= ?", Date.today)
                   .order("startdate, starttime")

    @events = apply_type_filter(@events)
  end


private


  def apply_type_filter(relation)
    case params[:filter]
    when "Men" 
      relation.men
    when "Women" 
      relation.women 
    when "Juniors"
      relation.juniors
    else
      relation
    end
  end

end
```